# Change click trigger to on ready from event

Tags: javascript, postmessage, document-ready

How can I change the following function to trigger on document ready instead of on click? I initially removed the button and changed `el.addEventListener('click', function()` to `document.ready(function()`, but not sure what I'm missing.

```
//when button clicked, event listener triggered(needs to be removed so this    
//functions ONLY on page load
var el = document.getElementById('button');

var getFontFamily = function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[i].rules.length; j++){

            if(document.styleSheets[i].rules[j].style.fontFamily){
                return document.styleSheets[i].rules[j].style.fontFamily;
            }
        }
    }

    return 'not-found';
};
//Sends event to receiving page to change font of iframed page. 
//needs to work on document.ready, not be triggered by button click on parent page
el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var data = getFontFamily();

    window.frames[0].postMessage(data, 'http://localhost:3000');

    console.log('Message sent -->');
});
```

**THE PAGE RECEIVING THE POST MESSAGE**

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e){
            document.body.style.fontFamily = e.data;

            console.log('<---Message received');
        }, false);
```

How can this be triggered on page ready?

Comment: possible duplicate of [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Comment: can u explain it properly? question is confusing.

Comment: @TechnoCrat, I've revised my question and code for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to execute on load and you're not using jQuery, you can just add an event listener for the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var data = getFontFamily();

    window.frames[0].postMessage(data, 'http://localhost:3000');

    console.log('Message sent -->');
})
```

Comment: What about the page receiving the message? It is using the following:
`window.addEventListener('message', function(e){
            document.body.style.fontFamily = e.data;

            console.log('<---Message received');
        }, false);`